# Regex catching repeating characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm learning Python regular expressions for the first time, and I'm having trouble with repeating characters.

I wrote this program to test for strings formatted like floating-point numbers:

```
for stuff in ["0", "1", "0.111", "0000001", ".011", "..0", "0..0"]:
    if match("[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+", stuff):
        print(stuff)
```

I was under the impression that `\.` specifies a `.` character, and `?` states that there can only be 0 or one of those characters.

However, I get this output:

```
0
1
0.111
0000001
.011
0..0
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I just want it to output floats only from the list.

Comment: Why not use `\d*\.\d+`?

Comment: because... i did not know you could do that.

Comment: Congratulations on your first question, and it appears that you've nailed most of it very nicely!  Maybe update your question stating what your desired outputs are as well?

Comment: Just edited with the desired output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.match` looks for a match at the beginning of the string, but allows unmatched characters to follow the match.

To force it to match all the way to the end, you can add a `$` character to the pattern:

```
match("[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$", stuff)
```

Comment: OHHH i see. I get it now. Thanks. Should i use ^ to specify the start of the string as well? so that asdf123.123 does not pass? or is that not nessesary?

Comment: If you use `re.search`, then you need the `^` at the beginning, but for `re.match` the search is implicitly anchored at the start of the string (but not the end of the string).

Comment: Ahh i see. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To get floats:

```
import re
stuffList = ["0", "1", "0.111", "0000001", ".011", "..0", "0..0"]
final_data = [i for i in stuffList if re.findall('\d+\.\d+|^\.\d+', i)]
```

Output:

```
['0.111', '.011']
```

Comment: You could shorten this to `\d*\.\d+`. Also, `re.match` is better than findall, if you're iterating over the list.

Comment: Oh god, I don't even know what findall does. This does seem simpler than my way. I'll investigate into this. Thanks.

Comment: Why is match better than findall?

Comment: @CarbonicBuckey Because `match` is guaranteed to match from the beginning, avoiding false positives through substring matching.

Comment: Ah ok. I need to read more about this. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is what is wrong with your regex. I think you have the answer in your own question. Since the '?' matches **0 or 1** occurences of the decimal '.', your regex matches even when the number does not have a '.' in it. That's why you see even the non-floats being printed.

Comment: yea but that's what i wanted. python float() accepts just simple integers without '.' so i wanted to replicate that. my problem was it was also accepting 123..123

Comment: Oops. Yes. You are right. I misunderstood.